# Simple slideshow with navigation overlay

Tags: php, css, navigation, slideshow

I'm currently re-designing my portfolio site & I would like to use the best non-flash method possible to create the following slideshow shown in my layout:

http://oi49.tinypic.com/xeifeq.jpg

I would only have 3 slides or so in the show, and I would like to overlay left/right nav buttons as shown.

So how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of options. With javascript libraries like jQuery, a lot of animations that needed flash once, can be easily done.

Try googling, jQuery Sliders

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use a pure CSS solution you'd get better browser support by using javascript to animate your slideshow.

There's roughly a billion javascript plugins to do this for you, but here's a good one - http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

You can tweak the CSS of most plugins to get the overlaying arrow effect you want. The method I would use for this is to set the container for the slideshow to position:relative and then set the arrows to be position:absolute ...so for example the left arrow can now be positioned using top:50% left:0

Good luck!